# C Programing Multiple Threads using pthread.h

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, process, pthreads

I'm trying to learning C Programing and multiple threads. I started programing some basic stuff [like the following], but I got stuck. Can someone give me a hand?

program.c

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 4

void *main_thread(void *threadID) {
    long tid;
    tid = (long)threadID;
    printf("main thread #%ld!\n", tid);
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}

void *first_thread(void *threadID) {
    long tid;
    tid = (long)threadID;
    printf("first thread #%ld!\n", tid);
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}

void *second_thread(void *threadID) {
    long tid;
    tid = (long)threadID;
    printf("second thread #%ld!\n", tid);
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}

void *last_thread(void *threadID) {
    long tid;
    tid = (long)threadID;
    printf("last thread #%ld!\n", tid);
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}



int main () {
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc;
    long t;

    for (t=0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++) {
        printf("In main Function creating thread %ld\n", t);
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, first_thread, (void *)t);
        if (rc) {
            printf("ERROR; Return code from pthread_create is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }

    }


    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

I will keep updating the codes above as i figure new things out
*Hey guys. i did not compile it properly but now i figured out.
gcc -pthread -o main main.c

Comment: did yo read any books or doc for basic pthread programming?

Comment: Use pthread_join to wait for all threads in main.

Comment: i just started reading some online stuff now. but its kinda confusing.

Comment: You have a couple simple errors. First, move your `main` function to the end so that the other functions are declared before you try to use them. Second, `pthreads_create` should be `pthread_create`. If you can't figure those things out from the compiler output then you're going to have a tough time making progress on your own...

Comment: Its not clear how you want your "main thread" to interact with "3 other threads". Its also not clear what you mean by interact. You could get a better help if you explain these things.
My 2 cents, guessing what you mean. Maybe you want all 3 of your threads to have similar functionality, in that case, use single handler, not 3. And usually they should be data driven.

Comment: Please describe your *specific* problem. "I am really unable to figure this one out" ain't.

Comment: My problem is that I can't figure out how to do thread. I keep on getting syntax errors or something. I'm trying to create a sample program for this. For example 1 main thread and it passes argument to 3 more threads. just basic prints

Comment: "syntax errors or something". Now that's a programmer!

Comment: Read DaoWen's comment. There appears to be a healthy number of people that agree with it (myself included), so perhaps consider it as having some merit and address the issues it points out.

Comment: i did i shifted main down and changed pthread_create, but i still got declaration error.

Comment: i got it working by using "gcc -pthread -o main main.c"

Answer (score 1):

This code will calculate the value of e^x by calculating terms of its series ,
in each term we need to calculate power of a number(in this program it is x) and factorial of each corresponding power.

since these two calculations are independent so we make two threads for these two functions that will be run parallel.

after calculating values of these two function (end of these two threads) we need to merge the results (i mean power/factorial) and then we add all these results in another parallel thread which will run after these two threads.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

long double x,fact[150],pwr[150],s[1];
int i,term;

void *Power(void *temp)
{   
    int k;

    for(k=0;k<150;k++)
    {
        pwr[k] = pow(x,k);
    //printf("%.2Lf\n",pwr[k]);
    } 

    return pwr;
}

void *Fact(void *temp)
{
    long double f;
    int j;

    fact[0] = 1.0;

    for(term=1;term<150;term++)
    {
        f = 1.0;

        for(j=term;j>0;j--)
        f = f * j;

        fact[term] = f;
        //printf("%.2Lf\n",fact[term]);
    }

   return fact;
}

void *Exp(void *temp)
{
    int t;
    s[0] = 0;   

    for(t=0;t<150;t++)
    s[0] = s[0] +  (pwr[t] / fact[t]);

    return s;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t thread1,thread2,thread3;  

    printf("Enter the value of x (between 0 to 100) (for calculating exp(x)) : ");
    scanf("%Lf",&x);

    printf("\nThreads creating.....\n");
    pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,Power,NULL); //calling power function
    pthread_create(&thread2,NULL,Fact,NULL);  //calling factorial function
    printf("Threads created\n");

    pthread_join(thread1,NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2,NULL);
    printf("Master thread and terminated threads are joining\n");
    printf("Result collected in Master thread\n");

    pthread_create(&thread3,NULL,Exp,NULL);
    pthread_join(thread3,NULL);

    printf("\nValue of exp(%.2Lf) is : %Lf\n\n",x,s[0]);

    exit(1);
}
```